# make an object into array and then push another object to the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

question guys, I have this type of object:

```
activities: Object
       activitiy: some activity
       date: some date
       level: some level
```

what I am trying to achieve here is to make it like this

```
activities: Array[1]
    [0]Object
```

then what i want to do is push to the array of activities

```
activities.push(newobject);
```

This is not the right logic:

```
activities = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
return [value];});
```

So what should I do to achieve what I want. Above will just put each value of the object as an array value instead of the whole object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
activities = [activities];
```

to transform `activities` into an array that initially contains the original object. Then you can push new items into `activities` since it's now an array.

Comment: perfect. MUCH easier than I thought